# Load a bitmap to a static member variable

Tags: c++, bitmap, static

I'm new to stack overflow... anyway I'm trying to load a bitmap a static bitmap pointer inside of a class "map". The reason why I'm using static is because there's pretty much only going to be one map that I'm testing my game with and I can't think of a good instance name for the class, but I'm getting the unresolved external symbol error. Can someone please tell me what's going on?

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_audio.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_acodec.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class game
{
public:
    static void initializeSetup()
    {
        al_init();
        al_create_display(800,600);
        al_init_image_addon();
    }
};

class map
{
private:
    static ALLEGRO_BITMAP *tile;
public:
    static void initializeSetup()
    {
        tile = al_load_bitmap("Resources/Ancient_Block_01.bmp");
    }
    static void draw()
    {
        al_draw_scaled_bitmap(tile, 0, 0, 256, 256, 0, 0, 512, 512, 0);
    }
};

int main()
{
    game::initializeSetup();
    map::initializeSetup();
    for(;;)
    {
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
        map::draw();
        al_flip_display();
    }
}
```

You can neglect the stuff related to draw() I think, mainly just the initializeSetup() is causing the problem.

Comment: Did you specify all the necessary libraries for linking?

Comment: Also note you need `ALLEGRO_BITMAP *map::tile = NULL;` outside your `map` class

Comment: I believe I did link the libraries, I think the only libraries needed for image addons is just #include<allegro5/allegro_image.h>

Comment: You don't show the error in your question explicitely, but I believe your problem is covered from my 2nd comment.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, but I can't find the upvote button for the comment. People say hover over it with the mouse and there should be an arrow but I don't see anything sorry.

Comment: _"... but I can't find the upvote button for the comment ..."_ It appears if you hover mouse at the left side of the comment.

Comment: I'll be sure to vote up once I have 15 reputation.

Comment: Don't wrap your head around it, I don't care a lot. Glad it helped you ;) ... By the way there's an answer I've given in the marked duplicate. It doesn't address your problem, though you're able to upvote it, if you deem it useful for other researchers.

Comment: Haha true, 1 to 17917 votes... well anyways, thanks for helping others out. Keep doing what you're doing! :D